# Use filename incrementor to replace text in files

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a lot of files which are exactly the same.

```
in.1.nbs
in.2.nbs
```

and so on. upto

```
in.100.nbs
```

I need to replace the following strings in the file  with these incrementors 1,2,3,...100 present in the file. $j = 1 in  in.1.nbs, $j = 2 in in.2.nbs and so on.

```
file : in.1.nbs 

 this is in the first line in.Au-$j.nbs
 5th line is min.$j.out
 10th line is data.$j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the numbers 1 to 100, using `sed` to replace the placeholder with each value inside the file which is named accordingly:

```
for i in {1..100}; do 
     sed -i "s/\$j/$i/g" in.$i.nbs; 
done
```

The `{a..b}` construct is a bash-ism, if you are working in another shell you could loop over the output of `seq` instead:

```
for i in $(seq 1 100); do
...
```

Comment: thanks. I initially had trouble with replacing the placeholder, got the logic now.